# Adding custom headers to a response from an upstream server in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, njs

I am trying to add a custom response header to the response from an upstream server in Nginx based on the response body.

For simplicity, let this custom header be the *SHA1* hash of the response body. To accomplish this, I'm attempting to use the njs scripting module for Nginx.

I've referred to the examples in the [njs-examples repository](https://github.com/nginx/njs-examples#modifying-response). However, those examples treat the headers and body sections separately, and I'm struggling to combine them to achieve my goal.

Here is my current configuration:

```
# nginx.conf

load_module modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;

events {}

http {
    js_path "/etc/nginx/njs/";
    js_import main from hello.js;  

    # Configuration containing list of application servers
    upstream app_servers {
        server flask:5000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            js_body_filter main.hello;
            proxy_pass http://app_servers/;
        }
    }
}
```

```js
# hello.js

function hello(r, data, flags) {
    var val = data.length;
    ngx.log(1, val);
    r.headersOut["X-Hello"] = val;
    r.sendBuffer(data, flags);
}

export default { hello };
```

However, when I send a request to my Nginx server, I don't see the `X-Hello` header in the response.

Is there a way to achieve my use case using njs scripting in Nginx? If not, what alternative approaches should I consider, such as implementing a custom Nginx module? Any suggestions or guidance on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I am running this setup on a Docker container with the [official nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) with some script for hot-reloading. If needed, I can share the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` as well.

Comment: Can you make it work if you include all the javascript code directly within your configuration file instead of loading it from another location? I am not experienced enough on this tooic but i would suggest starting there and see if you can accomplish it that way, the most basic way that is.

Comment: Actually, I was able to find a solution here https://nginxcommunity.slack.com/archives/C02MFGJQ7GU/p1694513169714039

Comment: need to login to view.. anywhere else that info exists? It would be nice if you added your solution, properly formatted - it would help others like you

Answer (score 1):

Answered by Liam Crilly on [Nginx community slack](https://app.slack.com/client/T017X0LHM2T/C02MFGJQ7GU).

> This probably won’t work, because NGINX will have sent the response
> headers to the client before reading the entire body. So by the time
> you’ve read the response body it will be too late to modify the
> headers.

> You can try using a `js_header_filter` function for that (to use
> `res.length`) but as I said, the headers are already sent before the
> body is received. I don’t think it will work

> Thinking again about this. You could do it with Trailers so long as
> the client accepts it.
>
> Use `js_header_filter` to switch to chunked
> transfer encoding, delete the content-length header, and define a
> trailer.
>
> Use `js_body_filter` to collect and hash the body, send the
> body, and then send the hash in the trailer we defined above.

> OK, so I couldn’t let this drop :lolsob: Here’s a solution that adds a
> SHA-1 hash of the response as a trailer. Not sure if that solves your
> problem,  @Gaurav Jain, but I had fun finding out!

`nginx.conf` snippet

```
js_import conf.d/body.js;
js_set $body_hash body.get_hash;

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
        js_body_filter body.set_hash;
        add_trailer Body-Hash $body_hash;
    }
}

server {
    listen 9001;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

`body.js`

```js
var hash = "";
var res = "";
var buf = 0;
function set_hash(r, data, flags) {
    if (data.length) buf++;
    res += data;      // Collect the entire response,
    if (flags.last) { //  until we get the last byte.
        try {
            hash = require('crypto').createHash('sha1').update(res).digest('base64');
            r.sendBuffer(res, flags);
            ngx.log(ngx.INFO, `FILTERED ${res.length} bytes in ${buf} buffers`);
        } catch (e) {
            ngx.log(ngx.ERR, `ERROR ${e}`);
            r.sendBuffer("", flags);
        }
    }
}

function get_hash() {
    return hash;
}

export default { set_hash, get_hash }
```

`Test`

```
curl -i localhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.25.2
Date: Wed, 13 Sep 2023 21:38:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Aug 2023 17:03:04 GMT
ETag: "64dbafc8-267"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
Body-Hash: xRo/Dm3k64AtVjCUHD/Z4dDvrks=
```